# DIV partially hides under Fixed Navigation

Tags: html, css

I am developing this website which includes fixed navigation on top. When I came to start developing the main content of the site, the DIV container holding the content is hiding partially under the fixed navigation.

One can see this following this URL: http://rcb.com.mt/wordpresstesting/WebsiteTest/product-feautres.html

When I added top margin in the top to this container it worked fine but not when you resize and website becomes responsive. Can anyone suggest me the changes that are require to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding following scripts

```
// If you put your code at the bottom of the page to avoid needing`$(document).ready`, it gets even simpler:

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    var newMarginTop = $('#header').height();
    $("#superContainer").css("margin-top", newMarginTop);
}).trigger('resize');


// Another way to do that same thing

$(document).ready(newMargin);
$(window).on('resize', newMargin);

function newMargin() {
    var newMarginTop = $('#header').height();
    $("#superContainer").css("margin-top", newMarginTop);
}


// Another technique is to`.trigger()`one event inside the other:

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    var newMarginTop = $('#header').height();
    $("#superContainer").css("margin-top", newMarginTop);
});
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```